# Ionic ngFor first value not setting

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm running a simple `*ngFor` loop on a form row, and i'm setting the default value to 0, but for some reason it ignores the first row and leaves it blank, then sets the rest correctly?

**HTML**

```
<form #hoursForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">
      <ion-grid>
          <ion-row *ngFor="let user of userList">
            <ion-col>
              <ion-input name="hours" type="number" value="0" #userHours="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.hours" required></ion-input>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
  </form>
```

**Result**

```
User1 : ,
User2 : 0,
User3 : 0
```

As you can see, i'm setting `value="0"`, but it seems to ignore the first row and set the other rows as 0? Everything works flawlessly, the two way binding and form submit, etc, and this doesn't effect the functionality of the form, but its just annoying as I have to click the first row and manually set it to `0`.

Has anyone come across this before, or experienced anything similar?

Comment: What looks like userList ? also, I don't think  you should use value with ngModel :)

Comment: You could set the default value in the `userList` declaration in the **.ts** file and stop using the `value` attribute.

Comment: I thought about this, but just thought id see if anyone had experienced a similar issue so i could fix it the way its working at the moment :) thanks for the feedback!